# iPhone Mail or GMail apps settings for Gmail label notification

Tags: iphone

I am just wondering how can I set the settings of iPhone Mail App or even GMail apps that could make notification for new incoming message on particular Gmail label and not the inbox only.

I would appreciate if anyone could share how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are a free gmail account I don't think it is possible in either the mail or Gmail app.

It's possible using [Exchange ActiveSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_ActiveSync) and the mail app but [Google hasn't allowed this to be setup since 2013](https://support.google.com/a/answer/135937?hl=en) for free Gmail accounts.

It should be possible if you are a google apps user.

[Apple's instructions for setup for exchange account in mail](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201729).

Once the account is set up go to "Fetch New Data" in Settings > Accounts and Passwords. Click the account and select the mailboxes to be pushed.

Comment: I am a Gsuite user and I am using the Gmail app on an iPhone. I still cannot set up notifications for specific labels. Do you know if this will be added in the future (it exists for Android Gmail app users)?

Comment: My guess is probably not, it looks like the feature has been on Android since [June 2013](https://lifehacker.com/customize-the-alerts-for-gmail-labels-to-tame-informati-512603766).

Comment: From what I understand it was also available on iPhone but was removed...